# How to remove h-tag an replace it with span-tag instead (preg_replace?)

Tags: php, joomla, replace

I want this:

```
<h2>My Headline</h2>
```

to this:

```
<span class="h2">My Headline</span>
```

I tried this, but this is just a way to remove the h-tag with the content :/

```
$introtext = preg_replace('/<h2[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/h2[^>]*>/', '', $introtext);
```

Maybe there is a solution to "convert" all h-tags into span-tags with the right class?

Thanks for support.

Another idea to change the tags, was this:

```
$introOld = array('/<h2>/','/</h2>/');
$introNew = array('<span class="h2">','</span>');
$introtext = preg_replace($introOld, $introNew, $introtext);
```

Maybe this will be help to show, what I mean/want.

I have on content ($introtext) and to views (teaser [categoryView] and detail [articleView]).
For the categoryView I want change all h-tags into span-tags, because of the category description.
If the articleView is shown, h-tags are okay.

Comment: is this a homework assignment or something?

Comment: Bear in mind that your replacement is invalid—you'll need `</span>`, not `</h2>`. Also, *why* do you want to do this? There may be a better solution (changing the styling of your `h2` elements with CSS, for example.) Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/300836

Comment: Oh. Thanks. `<span class="h2">My Headline</h2>` is wrong. That meant `<span class="h2">My Headline</span>`

Comment: @Matt Gibson: This solution is okay, if i want just style my heading. But i need another tag to remove the "importance" of the headings [SEO].

Comment: @deathride: What if you encounter a tag containing whitespace? for example: `</ h2>`. Common? No. Possible: yes.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I would exclude this. The tags will be generated by user (backend - wysiwyg including auto correction).

Comment: @deathride: That's just an example of things you can't reliably foresee when parsing HTML with regular expressions, which is exactly why I suggested using a parser, like `DOMDocument` is: it's a lot easier to read (and maintain) than a regular expression is, and it's equipped to deal with things like nested tags, or strangely formed markup

Comment: Depending on how your users edit content in Joomla, you may be able to just replace the style that they're choosing in the editor that produces the `h2` with one that produces a `span` instead...

Answer (score 1):

For the record: Markup (HTML/XML) and Regex don't mix well. Regular expressions just can't cope with the complexities of markup languages, so any attempt at processing markup using regex [will end in tears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1230836) eventually. Luckily, PHP has a DOM parser you can use, which makes it relatively easy to do what you want to do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourMarkup);
$headers = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
foreach ($headers as $header)
{
    $span = $dom->createElement('span', $header->nodeValue);//create span with h2's value
    $span->setAttribute('class', 'h2');
    $header->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $header);//replace element
}
```

Granted, this code is a tad verbose, but then DOM api's tend to be verbose. Anyway, the `DOMDocument`, `DOMElement` and `DOMNode` classes are [well documented](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Read through the docs, take notes and get cracking.